# Displaying php curl Json Array Data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, curl

I am trying to Displaying PHP curl json array data in javascript.

if I echo

```
// curl output

$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $response;
```

I will be having this data in the format below as my output

```
{"items":[{"id":"1","food":"rice","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},
{"id":"2","food":"beans","Amount":"200","condition":"paid"},
{"id":"3","food":"yam","Amount":"50","condition":"not paid"},
{"id":"4","food":"tomatoes","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},
{"id":"5","food":"potato","Amount":"700","condition":"paid"}]}
```

Question is how can I display the data in Javascript?

I have tried the code below but am having error "`Undefine`".

Can someone help me out?

Below is the code of my output in Javascript.

```
    function loadData(){
$.post('json.php',
function(response){

    $.each(JSON.parse(response),

function(i,v){  


$('.info').append('<li><div class="msg-lhs"><span>'+v.id+'</span> <span>'+v.food+'</span> <span>'+v.Amount+'</span> <span>'+v.condition+'</span></div></li>');

});

$('.info').animate({scrollTop: $('.info').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);

});
```

Comment: The array you want to access is in the key `items` you need to iterate over that like: `JSON.parse(response).items`

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: ... replace `JSON.parse(response)` with `JSON.parse(response).items`. if it works think why, if not tell me the error :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is really messed up with your code, but I came up with a slightly different approach that works fine.

**Note: assuming that you're getting data from your `curl` request fine.**
just parsed your result outside the loop iteration and using `forEach` loop.

```
var response = '{"items":
     [{"id":"1","food":"rice","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},\
      {"id":"2","food":"beans","Amount":"200","condition":"paid"},\
      {"id":"3","food":"yam","Amount":"50","condition":"not paid"},\

      {"id":"4","food":"tomatoes","Amount":"100","condition":"paid"},\
      {"id":"5","food":"potato","Amount":"700","condition":"paid"}]}';
var parsed = JSON.parse(response)
parsed.items.forEach(function(v) {
$('.info').append('<li><div class="msg-lhs"><span>'+v.id+'</span>    
    <span>'+v.food+'</span> <span>'+v.Amount+'</span> 
    <span>'+v.condition+'</span></div></li>');
});
$('.info').animate({scrollTop: $('.info').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mubin/jw619Lqq/)